# How can I Scroll the contents of Gallery Vertically

Tags: android

I am trying to Scroll the contents of a Gallery, but not able to do that. I put a scroll in the Gallery xml so that the contents of the Gallery can be scrolled, but by performing that the Gallery stopped scrolling Horizontally also. So anyone kindly give me a solution for how to Scroll the contents of Gallery?

Comment: Go back over your old questions and mark them as answered. (Click the tick on the left next to the answer under the numbers). This will encourage more people to answer your questions.

Comment: And on the question, would not a list view, or a grid view with one column do what you want?

Comment: @Houcine I had already used scrollView but its doesn't work.

Comment: scrollView will work for you ,you can add imageView on your scrollView,and add your images to those imageViews , and then you can scroll vertically ,

Comment: @suri sahani, if you say "ScrollView doesn't work" you must explain, why it doesn't work, post some code, a logcat, if any exceptions occur. Help people help you!

Comment: @ suri sahani & Egor : i'm sure that the scrollview will work for him , more than that , there is no vertical gallery in Android, but he can create a custom listView or using scrollView to resolve his problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know .... Gallery can't be scrolled vertically.. But you can achive the same effect using a listview wrapped inside linearlayout.

Comment: can you provide me such example or link.

Comment: as said ... use   <LinearLayout > <Linearlayout layout_width   layout_weight="3" >.... <ListView>....</ListView>  </LinearLayout></LinearLayout>   ... set layout_weight property for the linearlayout as per your requirement. you will get a view that can be scrolled vertically..